# What is this Filezilla Connections Timeout setting for?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

What is this setting for, please?

(I'm not having much luck finding the documentation on it)

[image]

Comment: It tells you how many seconds a client can be idle for before it is disconnected.

Comment: ok. so it's the CLIENT idle time. wouldn't that alwasy kick in first before the no TX time?  and ... BTW - this question is for our ftp server, for our company. so it's a pretty relevant sys admin topic. Yes? (we have 50+ companies ftp'ing their data to us every few mins)

Comment: Well, if it's less than the "no transfer timeout", it would kick in first, yes.  The "no transfer timeout" setting is used to prevent connection keep-alive techniques that rely on, for example sending a `LIST` command every so often.  Regarding the topicality of the question, you are free to edit it (such as adding your comment into the question), which will put it in a review queue for community members to vote on whether to reopen it or not, but I wouldn't get my hopes up.  I wouldn't have put it on hold unless I was confident the community would have eventually.  But, you're free to try.

Answer (score 2):

The connection timeout on an FTP server tells you how many seconds a client can be idle for before it is disconnected.